# Edit a specific row in a file

Tags: c

I have a txt file like this:

```
"shoes":12
"pants":33
"jacket":26
"glasses":16
"t-shirt":182
```

**I need to edit the number of jacket** ( from 26 to 42 for example ).
So, I have wrote this code, but I don't know how to edit a specific row where there is the word "jacket":

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char row[256];
    FILE *fp;

    if (!(fp=fopen("myfile.txt","rw"))) {
        printf("Error");
        return 1;
    }

    while (!feof(fp)){
        fgets(row, 256, fp);
        // if there is the "jacket" in this row, then edit the row
    }

    fclose (fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there is no easy solution to this.

A common method is to write all lines (modified or not) to a temporary file, and then move the temporary file over the existing file.

Comment: is there a easiest solution in C++ ?

Comment: @xRobot The language doesn't matter, the problem and the solution are the same.

Comment: Why cant we open the file in "r+" mode and use `ftell`, `fseek` combination and overwrite the file in place?

Comment: @PavanManjunath It possible, at least as long the length we write is _shorter or equal_ to the old text. If it's longer, we will overwrite the existing text of the next line.

Answer (score 4):

If the number of characters in the old and new value is the same (your case), you can overwrite them:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("x.txt", "r+"); // note: r+, not rw
char row[256];
char* string = "\"jacket\":"; // note: contains punctuation
char* newvalue = "42\n"; // note: contains a line break

while (!feof(fp)) // note: feof is bad style
{
    long pos = ftell(fp);
    fgets(row, 256, fp); // note: might add error handling

    // check if there is the "jacket": in this row,
    if (strncmp(row, string, strlen(string)) == 0)
    {
        // check that the old length is exactly the same as the new length
        // note: assumes the row contains a line-break \n
        if (strlen(row) == strlen(string) + strlen(newvalue))
        {
            // then edit the row
            fseek(fp, (long)(pos + strlen(string)), SEEK_SET);
            fputs(newvalue, fp);
            fseek(fp, (long)(pos + strlen(string) + strlen(newvalue)), SEEK_SET);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Too bad, cannot change value");
        }
    }
}
fclose(fp);
```

You might want to change your file format to include padding, for example:

```
"shoes":12____
"pants":33____
"jacket":26____
"glasses":16____
"t-shirt":182___
```

Here `_` visualizes a space character; this file format supports a maximum of 999999 items. If you do such a change, you need to change the code above to check and adjust the number of spaces, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Text Files are not like Database where we can modify single row or column in one shot that too in c/c++ it is very difficult it comes at a cost of duplicate coding.

Answer (score 0):

Write a script and use sed (stream editor) to edit a specific stream.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to use gawk.

```
gawk -f edit_row.awk <myfile.txt >tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt myfile.txt
```

edit_row.awk

```
BEGIN {
    FS = ":"
}

{
    if ($1 == "\"jacket\"") {
        print $1 ":" 42
    } else {
        print
    }
}
```

If you really wanted to do it in c you could use the tmpfile() function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char row[256];
    char *file_name = "myfile.txt";
    FILE *file_pointer;
    FILE *temp_file;

    char col_a[101] = "";
    unsigned int col_b = 0;
    char filter[] = "\"jacket\"";
    size_t filter_length = sizeof(filter) - 1;

    file_pointer=fopen(file_name,"r+");
    temp_file=tmpfile();

    while (fgets(row, 256, file_pointer) != NULL) {
        if (strncmp(row, filter, filter_length) == 0) {
            fprintf(temp_file,"%s:46\n", filter);
        } else {
            fprintf(temp_file, "%s", row);
        }
    }


    rewind(temp_file);
    rewind(file_pointer);

    while (fgets(row, 256, temp_file) != NULL) {
        fputs(row, file_pointer);
    };

    fclose(file_pointer);
    fclose(temp_file);
    return 0;
}
```