# How to edit a row in a text file with C++?

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I have a txt file like this:

```
"shoes":12
"pants":33
"jacket":26
"glasses":16
"t-shirt":182
```

I need to replace the number of jacket ( from 26 to 42 for example ). So, I have wrote this code, but I don't know how to edit a specific row where there is the word "jacket":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream f("file.txt");
    string s;

    if(!f) {
        cout< <"file does not exist!";
        return -1;
    }

    while(f.good()) 
    {       
        getline(f, s);
        // if there is the "jacket" in this row, then replace 26 with 42.
    }


    f.close(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is in C++, so it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Do you want a solution in C, C++ or both?

Comment: in C or C++... doesn't matter :)

Comment: I know that other programs use a text files to save and edit preferences. So, How can he do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to modify data in a text file, you'll generally have to read
the entire file into memory, make the modifications there, then rewrite
it.  In this case, I'd suggest defining a structure for the entries, 
with `name` and `quantity` entries, equality defined as equality of the
names, and an overloaded `operator>>` and `operator<<` to read and write
it from the file.  You're overall logic would then use functions like:

```
void
readData( std::string const& filename, std::vector<Entry>& dest )
{
    std::ifstream in( filename.c_str() );
    if ( !in.is_open() ) {
        //  Error handling...
    }
    dest.insert( dest.end(),
                 std::istream_iterator<Entry>( in ),
                 std::istream_iterator<Entry>() );
}

void
writeData( std::string const& filename, std::vector<Entry> const& data )
{
    std::ifstream out( (filename + ".bak").c_str() );
    if ( !out.is_open() ) {
        //  Error handling...
    }
    std::copy( data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Entry>( out ) );
    out.close();
    if (! out ) {
        //  Error handling...
    }
    unlink( filename.c_str() );
    rename( (filename + ".bak").c_str(), filename.c_str() );
}
```

(I'd suggest raising exceptions in the error handling, so that you don't
have to worry about the else branches of the `if`s.  Except for the
creation of the `ifstream` in the first, the error conditions are exceptional.)

Comment: If the entire file has to be read and kept in the memory, then is that how the SQLite DB manage (which is apparently single file based)? Is there any simpler way of editing the row descripter with C++11? Possibly can you edit your answer for rewriting in file, exactly the same amount of data? [e.g. Overwriting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10226445/514235) a field in the file, which is 0 and making it to 1.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not possible in the naive way. Let's say you want to edit said row but write a larger number, there won't be any space in the file. So usually eidts in the middle are done by rewriting the file or writing a copy. Programs may use memory, temp files, etc and hide this from a user, but chaning some bytes in the middle of a file will only work in very restircted environments.

So what you'll want to do is write another file.

```
...
string line;
string repl = "jacket";
int newNumber = 42;
getline(f, line)
if (line.find(repl) != string::npos)
{
    osstringstream os;
    os << repl  << ':' << newNumber;
    line = os.str();
}
// write line to the new file. For exmaple by using an fstream.
...
```

If the file has to be the same, you can read all lines to memory, if there is enough memory, or use a temp file for either input or output.