# how to fetch data from a txt file using fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

I am building a small application. in this i have saved some data in a txt file. i need to edit a value in particular row and column. i wrote a code to go to a particular line and fetch the values but i have tried almost everything to got a particular column and edit that value.

```
1000 400 120 110 800 110 150 500 0 1000
1000 400 90  150 800 120 150 600 0 1000
1000 400 80  60  **800** 132 150 700 0 1000
1000 400 120 60  800 123 150 200 0 1000
1000 400 111 80  800 143 150 700 0 1000
1000 400 30  90  800 155 150 500 0 1000
```

for example i have edit the highlighted value , which is the best way to do. i cannot paste my whole code as it is very long.
this is the one where i can go to a particular line

```
fstream& GotoLine(int num) {

infile.seekg(std::ios::beg);

            for (int i = 0; i < num - 1; ++i) {
                    infile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
            return infile;
    }
```

i would appreciate any help over this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit a row in a text file with C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225843/how-to-edit-a-row-in-a-text-file-with-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your file is formatted as fixed column size, my advice would be:

- prepare an array or a vector of `struct { size_t pos; size_t width}` to define the fields
- open the file in `ios::in | ios::out` mode
- read the file one line at a time with your `GotoLine` function up to the line you want to process
- note the index in the fstream with `tellg`
- read the interesting line in a char array with a size greater than the line - here I would use 64 to be large enough - with `istream::getline`
- as you have read the line as a plain array, you can rewrite the characters of one single field
- go back to beginning of line with `seekp`
- write the line back to the file

This is **not** a general method of editing a text file. It only works here because *as you have fields of fixed size* the edited line has exactly same size than original one, so it can be re-written in place. But **never** use it in a general case.

Comment: Thanks a lot Serge. i will try this out.